# bad auth Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.twqkk.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

Comment: The exception is clearly say what's wrong, you should check your auth configuration

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470